# How to create a number sequence such as "minutes:seconds"

Tags: java

Write a program that asks the user to enter the time as a sequence of digits and then displays the time as "minutes:seconds". Assume that if two or fewer digits are entered that the digits represent seconds. In this case, display a zero before the colon. If three or more digits are entered, the last two represent seconds.

```
Output needs to be: 
Enter cook time-> 123
Your time->  1:23
```

According to the instructions how does one create this sequence? I know how to scan in the user's time. I just need help differentiating between minutes and seconds.

Comment: `String#length`, `String#subString`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no end of ways you might achieve this, you could use modular maths, convert the input to a `String` and convert that to a `char` array or you could just use `String#substring`

For example...

```
    int value = 1;
    String text = Integer.toString(value);
    if (text.length() < 2) {
        if (text.length() == 1) {
            text = "0:0" + text;
        } else {
            text = "0:" + text;
        }
    } else {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 2) + ":" + text.substring(text.length() - 2);
    }
```

And yes, you could just have a 3 way `if-else` instead of the compound `if`, but that's up to you

Take a closer look at [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [`String#substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for more details

You should also take a look at the [Strings trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: Ok thank you. I was looking more for the use of 4-way if statements. The instructions above say "Assume that if two or fewer digits are entered that the digits represent seconds. In this case, display a zero before the colon." So then this would break up into "if (text == 1)" etc. etc. 1 standing for if there was only one digit it would be a second.

Comment: The way I have it setup, it already is a 4 layer if statement, it's just I compounded two of the levels. In fact, with a little thought the inner if-statement could be optimised more ;)